# Magento2: Cannot update wishlist list items with xml in module

Tags: magento2, layout

I am trying to add a 'low stock' banner to wishlist items that are low stock.

This works if I add my block to the theme xml file but doesn't if I add in a module wishlist_index_index.xml file.

I know my module layout update file is in the right place as I can add to the content (e.g. a footer block) but it does not want to update `customer.wishlist.items`.

My XML:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="customer.wishlist.items">
            <block class="Company\Module\Block\Product\Renderer\LowStock" name="customer.wishlist.stock" template="Company_Module::product/lowstock.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

In my module composer.json I added:

```
"suggest": {
    "magento/module-wishlist": "*"
},
```

But that has not helped.

Any ideas or do I just have to be resigned to this not working?